# Failed implicit conversion from Object<T> to Object<const T>

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, template-specialization

As practice I tried to make a wrapper around raw pointers to have cleaner memory management when using CUDA. Basically I made a PointerBase template that has a PointerBase specialization for const pointers. This template is the base template for a HostPointer and a DevicePointer template that manage memory on CPU side and GPU side respectively (but this is out of scope of this question). I struggle with the conversion from a `PointerBase<T>` object into the `PointerBase<const T>` specialization.

(Keep in mind this is more about practicing C++ templates than production use).

Here is a simple code demonstrating the behavior.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Pointer
{
    T* ptr_;

    Pointer() = default;
    Pointer<T>& operator=(const Pointer<T>& other) = default;

    operator Pointer<const T>() const { return Pointer<const T>(ptr_); }

    T* get() const { return ptr_; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Pointer<const T>
{
    const T* ptr_;

    Pointer() = default;
    Pointer<const T>& operator=(const Pointer<const T>& other) = default;

    const T* get() const { return ptr_; }
};

template <typename T>
T dereference(Pointer<const T> data)
{
    return *data.get();
}

int main()
{
    int value = 7.0;
    Pointer<int> ptr{&value};
    //int tmp3 = dereference(ptr); // not compiling
    int tmp4 = dereference(Pointer<const int>(ptr)); // compiling

    return 0;
}
```

This code fails to compile with the following error (gcc 8.4.0 on ubuntu 20.4, with c++14 standard)

```cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:41:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘dereference(Pointer<int>&)’
     int tmp3 = dereference(ptr); // not compiling
                               ^
main.cpp:32:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> T dereference(Pointer<const T>)’
 T dereference(Pointer<const T> data)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:32:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:41:31: note:   types ‘const T’ and ‘int’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers
     int tmp3 = dereference(ptr); // not compiling
                               ^
```

Why is the conversion operator not considered for calling the dereference function ?

I feel there is a connection to the fact that the `Pointer<const T>` type is a specialization of the `Pointer` template. But I still don't understand why a conversion is not happening.

I get the same result when defining a constructor in `Pointer<const T>` taking a `Pointer<T>` as a parameter.

Any help ?

PS : Interestingly, I get the same behavior with `std::shared_ptr`.

```cpp
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
T dereference(std::shared_ptr<const T> data)
{
    return *data.get();
}


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> sptr(new int[10]);
    int tmp1 = dereference(sptr); // not compiling
    //int tmp2 = dereference(std::shared_ptr<const int>(sptr)); //compiling

    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘dereference(std::shared_ptr<int>&)’
     int tmp1 = dereference(sptr); // not compiling
                                ^
main.cpp:4:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> T dereference(std::shared_ptr<const _Tp>)’
 T dereference(std::shared_ptr<const T> data) { return *data.get(); }
   ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:9:32: note:   types ‘const _Tp’ and ‘int’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers
     int tmp1 = dereference(sptr); // not compiling
                                ^
```

Comment: `//Pointer() = default;` will enable it as an aggregate if that's what you want. You need an overload for `dereference` too. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/dhrjoxae8). Pay attention to the clang error and implement the proper conversion too

Comment: Template matching happens before the implicit conversion so the compiler can't deduce the type for `dereference`